# Need Hack to Implement Music Player on Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jplayer

I'm using Jplayer plugin of Jquery to implement a Audio player on my website.

I have a scenario I:

When the player is loaded and user is not listening to any song and user browse website , my page can load as browser load. But when user is listening to song and I do browser load , it will relaunch the player and music will be disturbed . Thus We use ajax to get the page and load it without refresh the whole page and disturbing the user music experience.

Though I'm sure that its not possible, But Still I want to get myself convinced that Is there a Hack , where I can load 2 independed HTML on my web page and One will load as user browse the website and 2nd will have the player which will not be disturbed ?

Comment: When you refresh a page you are discarding everything from the current page. An AJAX way to load content is the way to go. Otherwise you can intercept users that are navigating away from the page first, before actually reloading the page itself, but this probably creates a really bad UX. The chances are, most users are unlikely to want to listen to your music and browse through your site at the same time—that might be a thing 10 years ago, but not today.

Answer (score 2):

You can use frames to keep the player undisturbed:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Frameset</title>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*,200">
    <frame src="index.html" name="content">
    <frame src="musicplayer.html" name="player">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Using the `name` you can address it in JavaScript from the content frame, for example to manipulate the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a separate window for the player with [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
window.open( "player.html", "player", "width=200, height=100");
```

This will open a small window for your player that is also not affected by browsing on the page.

There are more options for it, like showing toolbar and statusbar etc., but the browser support for those options vary.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way I did it. You can put the jPlayer html in the master (layout) page as a footer player or something and then load every page via AJAX in the main part if it's an Ajax request.

You could always use jquery to load content in the Ajax success function. If user refreshes page though it will always reload jPlayer because that can never be Ajax. Or if your doing MVC asp.net you can use partial views.